# OpenOffice / LibreOfiice / Calc - When i am searching for partial text in a column, if text contains the character ?, no results are given

Tags: string, search, libreoffice-calc

OpenOffice / LibreOfiice / Calc - I'm getting no result when I search for a partial text in a column, and the search text contains the character "?"!

For Example: `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A279;MATCH(IF(SEARCH($G$1;A80)=1;A80;"");$A$1:$A$200;0));"")`

If $G$1 is "aaa" the search formula for text string "aaaaaaaarchg" will result 1 (positive)

However if the  text string is "aaaaaaaarchg?" will result 0 (negative).

(? can be anywhere inside the text string).

Comment: Are the `ISERROR` and `INDEX` functions in your example required to explain the issue? If not, try to provide a minimal example,only showing the function that causes trouble, together with minimal example data.

Comment: Rephrased the question for a better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MATCH function is interpreting the `?` as part of a `regular expression` and not as a text character.

- Open the options window by Tools→Options...
- Expand the OpenOffice Calc group and select "Calculate"
- **UN**check the option "Enable regular expressions in formulas"

And then it should work as you expect.

Comment: @EliasEstatisticsEU You should mark lyrl answer as correct by clicking on the tick under the voting arrows.